# How to get and set data in crud from REST api, not from database and models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to use backpack to manupulate REST api data in my project.

I always used a backpack to administrate data using eloquent models without REST.

But now I want to request the data from api in controllers and show it in backpack crud tables.

I can request the data with guzzle, add multiple columns dynamically with `$this->crud->addColumns();`.

Could you tell me what method I should use inside my EntityCrudController `setup()` method to add the data like this? Thanks.

Using Laravel 5.8 with Backpack 3.5.
For REST using Slim framework 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m afraid it is not recommended to use Backpack with your custom REST API. Backpack depends on Eloquent to do everything related to database interaction, so you’d have to overwrite a lot of things.

While technically it is possible (you could create the operation methods in your EntityCrudController like store(), update(), destroy(), search() and call your API instead of Eloquent - it would be a lot of work. And it will probably be easier to just create CRUDs without Backpack.